# How to save middle portion of an image as wallpaper in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, wallpaper

Well i have build an app using flutter that fetch images from unsplash api and set them as wallpaper using flutter_wallpaper_manager package. Its successfully does that part, but the problem is the final result in homescreen wallpaper looks left aligned. It save the left portion of the image as wallpaper.
Now i wants to know is there any way that i can save the middle part of the image as wallpaper? if there, then how?

**Example:**

**Preview before setting-**
[image: This is the preview of a image before set.]

**Result after setting as wallpaper-**
[image: This is the result after setting as wallpaper.]

So as shown above, how to solve this problem and save the image as wallpaper as shown as wallpaper.

Comment: Please provide some more detail or either share some code.

Comment: @AnkushModi i added few image and also some info as you have asked.